# How do I prevent the deletion of ~/.emacs.d/auto-save-list/.saves-PID-HOSTNAME~ files?

Tags: auto-save, emacs26

I recently upgraded to Emacs 26.3 from a much older version of Emacs (22.x). One of the many changes I've noticed with Emacs 26.3 is that the `~/.emacs.d/auto-save-list/.saves-PID-HOSTNAME~` files are being deleted even when the emacs process is terminated with a SIGHUP, such as when I lose my connection to the remote server where Emacs is running. Is there a way to prevent that? I only want the `~/.emacs.d/auto-save-list/.saves-PID-HOSTNAME~` file to be deleted if I intentionally quit Emacs. That is how it worked in older versions of Emacs.

I rely on the existence of the `~/.emacs.d/auto-save-list/.saves-PID-HOSTNAME~` file to restore my session (i.e., re-open all of the files I had opened previously) whenever my emacs process is terminated. I have a `restart-session.el` that I've been using for over a decade that does this.

Comment: If you're going to downvote my question, I would appreciate a comment as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through the code, and it's not possible. I submitted a bug report to the Emacs developers about this (bug#39791), but the one that replied didn't seem inclined to agree with me that `~/.emacs.d/auto-save-list/.saves-PID-HOSTNAME~` files should be retained on `SIGHUP`. Another developer suggested I try `desktop-save-mode` instead of relying on these files to restore my terminated sessions.